# Bluetooth printer skipping lines of print

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

We are pairing a blue tooth printer with an android phone and trying to print a file. The printer has 16K memory. It is ignoring a few lines of the file randomly. Is there a method to ensure that the printer always prints the complete content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a buffer overrun. Depending on printer type, try:

1. Sending with smaller packets.
2. Sending with delays between packets.

Check if you can turn on some flow control (XON/XOFF etc.)